# Should use CGI.pm's header method to output the Content-Type header?

Tags: perl, header, cgi

If I'm using the [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) module in Perl, I can do this

```
$cgi = CGI->new();
$cgi->header(-type=>"text/html");
```

Or go for the classic

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
```

Does it matter which we use? Is there any difference between the two? Both seem to work.

For me I'd go for the first if I was using [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) anyway, but if not then I wouldn't bother loading the module for just one action. But just wondering if there is any thing on the subject?

Psy

Comment: `text/html` **not** `text\html`. You should have gotten `Unrecognized escape \h passed through ...` Are you not using `warnings`? Or, are you not posting the exact code you are using? Either way, *tsk*, *tsk*.

Comment: Sorry, that was just top of my head. I'm sure that people know the correct way to do it :)

Comment: OTOH, kudos for calling the `CGI` object `$cgi` rather than the really annoying `$query` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you have to print \r characters:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
```

is a legal way to express what you want to say.

Generally, I'd stick with what CGI offers.
It allows much more concise and readable code, and CGI knows a lot more about such details than you do.

Comment: Agreed. CGI is pretty big though, and so you take a bit of a run-time speed hit. CGI::Simple will do the job a little faster (assuming you have it installed).

Comment: @Psytronic: but the fact that you forgot the \r is my illustration of why it makes sense to use CGI.pm.

Comment: @Gavin: the speed hit won't be so bad unless you're using standalone CGI scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, you have to print `CRLF` pairs. That is not the same thing as "\r\n\r\n" unless you use `binmode STDOUT` first.

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
```

```
C:\Temp> t | xxd
0000000: 436f 6e74 656e 742d 5479 7065 3a20 7465  Content-Type: te
0000010: 7874 2f68 746d 6c0d 0d0a 0d0d 0a         xt/html......
```

You should use [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI). Or, if, like me, you do not want all the historical baggage, use [CGI::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Simple).

Answer (score 1):

In perl, the escape codes "\r" and "\n" are NOT guaranteed to be identical to "\015" and "\012".

If you want to print a CRLF for a network protocol, you should use "\015\012" or "\cM\cJ".

Here's the quote, direcly from perldoc perlop:

> All systems use the virtual "\n" to represent a line terminator,
>   called a "newline". There is no such thing as an unvarying, physical
>   newline character. It is only an illusion that the operating system,
>   device drivers, C libraries, and Perl all conspire to preserve. Not
>   all systems read "\r" as ASCII CR and "\n" as ASCII LF. For example,
>   on the ancient Macs (pre-MacOS X) of yesteryear, these used to be
>   reversed, and on systems without line terminator, printing "\n" might
>   emit no actual data. In general, use "\n" when you mean a "newline"
>   for your system, but use the literal ASCII when you need an exact
>   character. For example, most networking protocols expect and prefer a
>   CR+LF ("\015\012" or "\cM\cJ" ) for line terminators, and although
>   they often accept just "\012" , they seldom tolerate just "\015" . If
>   you get in the habit of using "\n" for networking, you may be burned
>   some day.

And more, similar info, from perldoc -f binmode:

> The operating system, device drivers, C libraries, and Perl run-time
>   system all conspire to let the programmer treat a single character (\n
>   ) as the line terminator, irrespective of external representation. On
>   many operating systems, the native text file representation matches
>   the internal representation, but on some platforms the external
>   representation of \n is made up of more than one character.
>
> All variants of Unix, Mac OS (old and new), and Stream_LF files on VMS
>   use a single character to end each line in the external representation
>   of text (even though that single character is CARRIAGE RETURN on old,
>   pre-Darwin flavors of Mac OS, and is LINE FEED on Unix and most VMS
>   files). In other systems like OS/2, DOS, and the various flavors of
>   MS-Windows, your program sees a \n as a simple \cJ , but what's stored
>   in text files are the two characters \cM\cJ . That means that if you
>   don't use binmode() on these systems, \cM\cJ sequences on disk will be
>   converted to \n on input, and any \n in your program will be converted
>   back to \cM\cJ on output. This is what you want for text files, but it
>   can be disastrous for binary files.

Answer (score 0):

the bad using

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
```

you can't add another header, here working example solution if you want to add **Content-Type** and **Cookies** using **CGI**

```
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie(-name  => 'CookieName', -value => 'CookieValue');

print $cgi->header( -cookie => $cookie,
                    -type    => 'text/html',
                    -charset => 'charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: It should be `-charset => 'utf-8'`.